# Can we use filename from wholeTextFile to save a dataFrame?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am having multiple files in S3 bucket in the format 'CHNC_P0BCDNAF_20200217'. I want to read each file one by one and do some processing in pyspark. After processing I am saving the processed parquet file in a datefolder which is splitted from the filename. **Each file processing should be seperate spark job**
For example for the above file datefolder will be 20200217.

I am able to split the filename and date from wholeTextFile, but cannot use the same to create datefolder

Comment: I think I showed you that in the other question

Comment: I couldnot get the working of the codes and change it to python spark. I have not worked with scala

Comment: The question title and content conflicts. What if on the original question I converted that to pyspark? Although should not be an issue.

Comment: My requirement is like, I am having multiple input files in s3. I want to process them one by one and store it in s3 output foler. Output folders are like each file should be saved inside a date folder. I want to create output datefolders from my input filename with format I have shown before. So I want to pass filename and datefolders as parameters to my spark submit command which I am running through data pipeline service.

Comment: bad approach - that's all and not necessary

Comment: I am processing history datas in aws. Is there a better way to do the same? Please help I am a newbie in spark and aws. Previously I was using NiFi to pass my parameters to my spark job.

Comment: separate Spark job does not seem necessary

Comment: as you can see, no one answered, reconsider the previous answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I used a shell script to list all my input filename in s3. Then I performed my spark job by iterating through each files. I am able to process each file as different spark job by passing the filename as argument to the spark job. I splitted the filename and date from wholetextfile itself and saved in my dataframe. Thankyou